# Parse.Config does not work on Parse Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I can't seem to find anything official about this: Does Parse.Config work on Parse Server? It used to work on Parse.com but when I try to migrate to Parse.Server, when trying the REST API it seem to fail:

`GET http://localhost:1337/parse/config`

Passing in my app ID. I read somewhere Config does not work on Parse Server, but wanted to confirm

Answer (score 2):

Although is not officially  supported as mentioned on [the docs](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Compatibility-with-Hosted-Parse#config),there is a way to make it work. It is still an experimental implementation though.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/283) & [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/726), you should set the environment variable: 
`PARSE_EXPERIMENTAL_CONFIG_ENABLED=1`

Then restart your node server. In case you deployed it on heroku for example you should on cli `heroku restart -a <APP_NAME>`

If that doesn't work I would suggest to simply add your route with your configuration options on your project's `index.js` file where express is initialized like so.

```js
var parseConfig = {
  "params": { /*...put your options here*/ }
};

// :one? is for old SDK compatibility while is optional parameter.
app.all('/parse/:one?/config', function (req, res) {
  res.json(parseConfig);
});
```

Comment: `PARSE_EXPERIMENTAL_CONFIG_ENABLED=1` you just saved my entire company. Thank you